# RatingBar change star value rating worth

Tags: android, android-layout, ratingbar

I am using the Android SDK RatingBar and trying to do 5 stars where each star is worth the value of 2, but it doesn't work. I want the rating "8" to fill only 4 stars, but it fills up all 5. Do I need to use a third-party library to solve this issue?

```
 <RatingBar
      android:id="@+id/user_rating_bar"
      android:isIndicator="true"
      android:rating="8"
      android:stepSize="0.01"
      android:max="10"
      android:numStars="5"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I think I've understood it wrong because if you simply need a double value you can proceed with [getNumStars()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getNumStars()) * 2 then you can do the reverse thing to convert a value of 2 to 1 star. A complete different thing is to have the value 1 graphically filling half the star, in this case you'll need to proceed with a custom view or using a third party library

Comment: @MatPag I don't think the double value is the problem. I would want a rating of 1 filling up half of the first star in the case of max 10 yes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this way:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:rating="2.5"
    android:numStars="5"
    />
```

If you use a `stepSize` value of `0.5`, with 5 stars you have 10 steps to fill, in this way each `0.5` is half a star and a rating of `8 * stepSize` will fill only 4 stars instead of 5.

In one line:

```
ratingBar.setRating(8 * stepSize);
```

Comment: not what I am looking for. I want it do if I have a rating of 8 with numStars of 5, I only want 4 out of 5 stars filled.

Comment: This is exactly what I did, you a have rating of 8, multiply it for the `stepSize` and you have the number of filled stars, i've updated th answer to add the `setRating` method

Comment: While it works for 8, it doesn't work for ratings like 7.50 which would make the rating 3.75 while the stepSize is 0.5

Comment: And in this specific case, with a rating of 3.75, you want 4 or 3.5 stars filled?